# Function returning constexpr does not compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++11, constexpr

Why doesn't this compile:
Could there be a problem with a `string` as a return type?

```
constexpr std::string fnc()
{
    return std::string("Yaba");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The constructor of `std::string` that takes a pointer to `char` is not `constexpr`. In `constexpr` functions you can only use functions that are `constexpr`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that before.

Comment: +1 and the reason that that constructor can’t be `constexpr` is that it has side-effects (namely allocation) that can’t be carried out at compile time.

Comment: But don't you think that this is (this particular example) bit silly? the string literal is const, so I think ctor of string should be made constexpr as to allow such constructs in the future.

Comment: @JonPurdy ctor CAN be constexpr

Comment: @smallB: A constant-expression constructor must be 1. declared `constexpr` 2. have a member-initializer part involving only potential constant-expressions and 3. have an empty body. It seems to me that `std::string` has to violate #2.

Comment: @JonPurdy I just said that a ctor CAN BE constexpr.

Comment: @smallB: Okay. I never said anything to the contrary.

Comment: @smallB You can't have a `constexpr` constructor for `std::string` that takes arbitrary length `const char*` and be safe. While it's true that string literals are constant expressions, there are plenty of things of type `const char*` that are not constant expressions. The `c_str` member of `std::string` comes to mind. Overloading on `constexpr` is not available to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @JonPurdy fair enough, that was just misunderstanding.