# constexpr with string operations workaround?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, constexpr

This [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779013/probrem-with-constexpr-how-to-resolve-it) explains why the code I have posted below does not work.  I have a follow-up question: is there a workaround that is conceptually equivalent, i.e., achieves compile-time string concatenation, but is implemented in a way that is actually supported by C++11? Using std::string is completely non-essential.

```
constexpr std::string foo() { return std::string("foo"); }
constexpr std::string bar() { return std::string("bar"); }
constexpr std::string foobar() { return foo() + bar(); }
```

Comment: So you want compile-time string concatenation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile-time "string" concatenation :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <char ... CTail>
struct MetaString
{ 
    static std::string string()
    {
        return std::string{CTail...};
    }
};

template <class L, class R>
struct Concatenate;

template <char ... LC, char  ... RC>
struct Concatenate<MetaString<LC ... >, MetaString<RC ... >>
{
    typedef MetaString<LC ..., RC ... > Result;
};

int main()
{
    typedef MetaString<'f', 'o', 'o'> Foo;
    typedef MetaString<'b', 'a', 'r'> Bar;

    typedef typename Concatenate<Foo, Bar>::Result FooBar;

    std::cout << Foo::string() << std::endl; //  foo
    std::cout << Bar::string() << std::endl; //  bar
    std::cout << FooBar::string() << std::endl; //  foobar
}
```

Comment: Is that actually going to work? I thought that you could only have one variadic pack.

Comment: @DeadMG: You can have more than one if it can be deduced (function template) / is used in a partial specialization. Or in otherwords, if the pack itself isn't top-level.

Answer (score 3):

Sprout C++ Libraries provide constexpr string. see:
https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout/blob/master/libs/string/test/string.cpp