# C++ assign static array with constexpr char array pointers at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I currently have a function that generate the type name for an array type. It's currently using other code that already runs at compile time. For example, for a variable such as `int data[4]`, the function returns the string `int[4]`:

```
template<typename Class, int Size>
constexpr auto getName(Class (&)[Size])
{
    // code that already runs at compile time:
    constexpr auto name = getName<Class>();
    constexpr auto length = getNumericString<Size>();
    constexpr auto size = getStrLen(name) + getStrLen(length) + 3;

    // code I would like to run at compile time:
    static char buffer[size] = {0};
    if (buffer[0] == 0) {
        auto i = 0, j = 0;
        while (name[j] != 0) {
            buffer[i++] = name[j++];
        }
        buffer[i++] = '[';
        j = 0;
        while (length[j] != 0) {
            buffer[i++] = length[j++];
        }
        buffer[i++] = ']';
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Is it possible to write the bottom part of that function to run at compile time somehow? It's just putting two `const char*` together with the `[` and  `]` characters to denote the array size. And if its possible, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Technically possible? Yes. Templates are Turing-complete. Read: [Template Metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming). But should you?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955940/how-to-concatenate-static-strings-at-compile-time

Comment: @IvanRubinson I'll use 'em everywhere I can.

Comment: As long as it's limited to [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and not used in production, I can live with that. There can be many issues from abusing ones programming language, especially when working in a team.

Comment: With `std::array<char, size>`, it would be easier...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814857/2065863 seems the closest to what I need but the sample code doesn't compile on this test: https://ideone.com/wIwBWW

Comment: Actually that solution requires external storage to be able to pass `const char*` as a template parameter, so its not useful for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The most tricky part is that you ask for a solution which returns a `const char*` (rather than something which owns the data).

As you notice in your example, the `const char*` needs a buffer to point to. This is tricky because `constexpr` functions are currently (C++17) **not allowed** to have a `static constexpr char buffer[size]{/* whatever*/};`. Instead, you can use a static data member of a templated helper class.

The following is a complete demonstration which I have tested with both clang 6.0.1 and GCC 8.1.1 using `-std=c++14`.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
constexpr const char* getName();

template<>
constexpr const char* getName<int>() {
  return "int";
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr const char* getNumericString();

template<>
constexpr const char* getNumericString<16>() {
  return "16";
}

constexpr std::size_t getStrLen(const char* str) {
  std::size_t ret = 0;
  while(str[ret] != '\0') ret++;
  return ret;
}

static_assert(getStrLen("") == 0, "");
static_assert(getStrLen("ab") == 2, "");
static_assert(getStrLen("4\0\0aaa") == 1, "");

struct Wrapper {
  const char* str;

  constexpr auto begin() const { return str; }
  constexpr auto end() const {
    auto it = str;
    while(*it != '\0') ++it;
    return it;
  }
};

template<class T, std::size_t size>
class Array {
 private:
  T data_[size]{};
 public:
  constexpr T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data_[i]; }
  constexpr const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return data_[i]; }
  constexpr const T* data() const { return data_; }
};

template<std::size_t buffer_size, class... Args>
constexpr Array<char, buffer_size> cat(Args... args) {
  Array<char, buffer_size> ret{};

  std::size_t i = 0;
  for(auto arg : {Wrapper{args}...}) {
    for(char c : arg) ret[i++] = c;
  }

  return ret;
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct StaticDataForConstexprFunction {
  static constexpr const char* name = getName<T>();
  static constexpr const char* length = getNumericString<N>();
  static constexpr std::size_t size = getStrLen(name) + getStrLen(length) + 10;

  using Buffer = Array<char, size>;
  static constexpr Buffer buffer = cat<size>(name, "[", length, "]\0");
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr typename StaticDataForConstexprFunction<T, N>::Buffer StaticDataForConstexprFunction<T, N>::buffer;

template<class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr const char* getName(T (&)[N]) {
  return StaticDataForConstexprFunction<T, N>::buffer.data();
}

int main() {
  int foobar[16];
  constexpr auto res = getName(foobar);
  std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
```