# Algorithm to produce C type declarations from AST

Tags: c, types, code-generation

I need to generate C code from an abstract syntax tree. Type declarations are tricky. Is there written down anywhere, an algorithm to do this?

There have been several previous questions here about going in the reverse direction. I'm not trying to parse C declarations, but to generate them.

I have tried examining the code for `cdecl` which is the only reasonably short program I know of that does this, but when I delete all the code that's clearly *not* the code for generating C declarations, I end up with an empty file, so I'm clearly missing something there.

The abstract syntax tree encodes C type semantics, where the kinds of nodes are:

- Basic types (`int`, `char` etc)
- Pointer to a type
- Array of a type (with or without size)
- Function taking a list of parameter types and returning a type

So the problem is just that of rendering this into C syntax.

Comment: "An abstract syntax tree" is very unspecific. If the AST models the C type syntax, then it should be trivial. If it doesn't, it's not possible to answer this question without knowing a lot more about the AST.

Comment: @rici It models the C type semantics, e.g. there are kinds of nodes for 'pointer to X', 'array of X', 'function taking this list of parameter types and returning this type'. The hard part is figuring out how to generate C syntax.

Comment: If it models the c type semantics then your AST must include language features like pointer and array. Without details of your AST it simply isn’t possible to respond.

Comment: @barny Okay, added details of AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re able to implement the AST in C++, the STL provides `std::type_info::name()`, which returns the name of the type `T`.  On some compilers, including MSVC, this returns the human-readable name.  On others, including `gcc`, it returns a mangled name.  GCC provides a `abi::__cxa_demangle` builtin to demangle it, and [Boost provides a more portable function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html) for this, `boost::core::demangle`.

To achieve runtime polymorphism, you can use the `typeid` operator to get a `std::type_info` object at runtime, or you can have every type of AST node inherit from an abstract base class.  That could have a pure virtual function `::name()`, whose implementation might be something like

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
  const char* AST<T>::name() {
    return boost::core::demangle( typeid(T).name() );
  }
```

Or something using a bunch of `#ifdef` blocks to support different compilers.

If you want to roll your own, [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783400/concatenate-compile-time-strings-in-a-template-at-compile-time/24784469) give some ways to concatenate constant strings at compile time using template metaprogramming.  There would be several fiddly bits, such as: putting qualifiers such as `const`, `volatile` and `signed` into a canonical order, expressing a pointer to `T(Args...)` as `T(*)(Args...)`, and the equivalent for pointers to arrays. If you wanted to eliminate all runtime overhead with template metaprogramming, you would probably define your own `type_name<T>` template, specialize it separately using `std::enable_if` and the `<type_traits>` library, and provide an override for compound types that concatenated the type names of the components with `*`, `(`, `)`, `[` and `]` in the proper way. If you can live with a small amount of overhead, you could just make them `const std::string` and concatenate them with `+`.

You would want to do this from the bottom up, starting with names for the simple types, and then providing implementations for array-of-t, pointer-to-array-of-T, etc. that recursively look up the names of the building blocks.  It’s very similar to pattern guards in a functional language.

Doing it in C would be much, much harder.

### Edit

Doing it in C would not necessarily be that much harder.  (In our chat, you say you’re actually doing it in Kotlin.)

You should consult the language standard (or [a recent draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) for the formal grammar, but the subset of the language you’re interested in seems to have three cases:

- Simple types, where you form a pointer by appending `*`,
- Derived types, where you form a pointer by adding `(*)` in the middle, and
- Pointers to derived types, where you already have something like `(**)` and you add another star to it.  (Don’t ever actually write three-star code!)

This can be written as an algorithm where types have a *left*, *middle* and *right* part. For simple types, *left* is the entire type, and the other two are empty.  For arrays, *left* is the element type and *right* is the bounds.  For function prototypes, *left* is the return type and *right* is the argument-list.  Either way, *middle* is empty.  For pointers to derived types, *middle* is the stars inside middle parentheses. So, for example, `double(*)[4][4]` has a *left* of `double`, a *middle* of `*` and a *right* of `[4][4]`.

Most operations have two special cases, depending on whether *middle* is empty or non-empty.  (These could be implemented as specializations of generics, pattern matches, overloaded object methods, or a case block.  Since we’re hypothetically doing this in C, we’d probably spell this `strlen(middle) ? ... : ...`.)

I’m going to spell string concatenation ⧺ from here on out.

If a given type has an empty *middle*, its name in C is *left* ⧺ *right*, and a declaration is *left* ⧺ " " ⧺ *name* ⧺ *right*.

If a given type has a non-empty *middle*, its name in C is *left* ⧺ "(" ⧺ *middle* ⧺ ")" ⧺ *right* and a declaration using it is *left* ⧺ "(" ⧺ *middle* ⧺ *name* ⧺ ")" ⧺ *right*.  For example, in the declaration `int(*callback)(handle)`, *left* is `int`, *middle* is `*`, *name* is `callback`, and *right* is `(handle)`.

Forming pointers to a type has three cases: if there is a non-empty middle, append `*` to *middle*.  If there is an empty middle and a non-empty *right*, set *middle* to `*`.  If both *middle* and *right* are empty, append `*` to *left*.

There are corner cases that need a bit more fiddling if you want to support `const` and `volatile` pointers, K&R style incomplete function types, or C++ references.